# htmlunit individual test pass but running in test suite fail

Tags: java, testing, automation, junit5, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit for testing some SAML SSO flow. I have multiple tests written and they work fine when running individually. When I run them in a test suite or run all the tests. Only 1 works fine and other fails. The problem seems to be that once the first page is requested using `webclient.getPage('url')` and a button is clicked to be redirected to next page. The click doesnt happen. When running the tests individually it clicks fine and works.

I am using htmlunit version 2.46.0 as follows the only static data shared between tests is the URLS and USERNAME AND PASSWORD:

```
private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";


public void test1() throws Exception {
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
            webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

            final HtmlPage loginPage= webClient.getPage(URL);
            assertThat(loginPage.getTitleText()).isEqualTo(LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE);

            HtmlButtonInput samlLoginButton = loginPage.getHtmlElementById("test");

            samlLoginButton.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);

            HtmlPage nextLoginPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
            
            assertThat(nextLoginPage.getUrl().toString()).isEqualTo(NEXT_LOGIN_URL);
}
}

public void test2() throws Exception {
//similar to above example
}
```

As I am using try with resources in java `webclient.close()` is called in the end.

Is there some thing more I need to do?

I also tried to setup `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` in Junit to setup the `webclient` and `close` it. But the result is same.

How can I stimulate the same behavior in test suite, as running individual test?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I fear this requires some discussion - please open an issue on github against HtmlUnit an i will try to help.
What is the problem you are facing with the failing tests? Any Exception/StackTrace?

Comment: @RBRi thank you for your help. The problem with tests when running in suite/together is that after getting the first page using `webclient.getPage('url')` and clicking on a button on that page to be redirected to next page. The click doesn't happen as it stays on the same page. So the test fails as there are assertions for next page `url`. Running the same tests individually works just fine.

Comment: @RBRi I updated the code in question with more details. Please let me know if you have any suggestion.